# Matching a simple route for a form using POST

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

New to Ruby here.
I keep getting: No route matches {:controller=>"home", :action=>"search"}
I have a simple form in my index view:

```
<%= form_tag(search_path) do %>

    <%= text_field(:search, nil, :placeholder => "yada yada") %>

    <%= submit_tag("Search") %>

<% end %>
```

And I have these routes:

```
   root to: "home#index"
   match 'search/:term', to: 'home#search', as: :search, via: [:post]
```

And the controller: home_controller.rb

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController

  def index
  end

  def search
    render 'index'
  end
end
```

I guess something is wrong with my rout where I try to match 'search/:term', but I can't figure out what.

Answer (score 0):

Your route definition states that you must have a "term" as part of the URL, ie:

```
http://example.com/search/some+term
```

Your form is POSTing to the /search patch - but is not providing a "term"

Make the term optional

```
match 'search(/:term)', to: 'home#search', as: :search, via: [:post]
```

or remove it all together (you're not referencing it in your form)

```
match 'search', to: 'home#search', as: :search, via: [:post]
```

and your problem should go away.

Comment: post 'search/:term' => 'home#search' would accomplish the same thing.